# oracle shard availability pending

Tags: oracle-12c

Trying to adjust Oracle DB 12.2 sharding configuration. Have one DB as the shard catalog and other two DBs as shards. Just want to test this functionality so run the tree DBs on the same machine in the same ORACLE_HOME. Using composite sharding method.

All the things done according to the official documentation. `GDSCTL> config` shows  nothing wrong as I can see. but:

```
GDSCTL>config shard
Name                Shard Group         Status    State       Region     Availability
----                -----------         ------    -----       ---------- --------
ape002              shrdgrp_oper        Ok        Replicated  reg_oper   PENDING
ape003              shrdgrp_arch        Ok        Replicated  reg_arch   PENDING
```

In the example in the documentation the states are "Deployed" and the Availabilities are "ONLINE" and "READ_ONLY". Every time I try to redeploy I get:

```
GDSCTL>deploy
deploy: examining configuration...
deploy: requesting chunk deployment on shards in shardgroup 'shrdgrp_oper'  via GSM ...
deploy: requesting chunk deployment on shards in shardgroup 'shrdgrp_arch' via GSM ...
deploy: shards configured successfully
GSM Warnings:
shrdgrp_oper ape002:ORA-45598: Shard  is in converted state , it should be either "PRIMARY" or "PHYSICAL STANDBY".
ORA-06512: at "GSMADMIN_INTERNAL.DBMS_GSM_DBADMIN", line 3865
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 79
ORA-06512: at "GSMADMIN_INTERNAL.DBMS_GSM_DBADMIN", line 3827
ORA-06512: at "GSMADMIN_INTERNAL.DBMS_GSM_DBADMIN", line 3861
ORA-06512: at line 1 (ngsmoci_execute)
shrdgrp_arch ape003:ORA-45598: Shard  is in converted state , it should be either "PRIMARY" or "PHYSICAL STANDBY".
ORA-06512: at "GSMADMIN_INTERNAL.DBMS_GSM_DBADMIN", line 3865
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 79
ORA-06512: at "GSMADMIN_INTERNAL.DBMS_GSM_DBADMIN", line 3827
ORA-06512: at "GSMADMIN_INTERNAL.DBMS_GSM_DBADMIN", line 3861
ORA-06512: at line 1 (ngsmoci_execute)
```

And in shard catalog I get:

```
SQL> alter session enable shard ddl;
ERROR:
ORA-02521: attempted to enable shard DDL in a non-shard database
```

Please tell me how to get it to work.